# Set CQWP query to return just user documents, not built in files

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have created a out the box team site, and in a document library I have uploaded 3 files. (These files could be in different libraries)

I have added a Content Query WebPart to my page, and set the query to

- Source: Show items from all sites in this site collection
- List Type: Document Library
- Content Type: Document Content Types - Document - Include Child Content types
- Sorted by Created Items.

When it displays the results to me I get the following:
[image: CQWP results]

I don't mind editing the Webpart XML if needs be, but how do I ensure that it only shows "MS-Office type documents" so that only "New User Handbook", "Dev Invoice April", and "Account details" are showing in my example below?

Also in the Site Assets library I have a OneNote file of Content Type Document. Is there a reason why this isn't showing up here?

Comment: Have you tried to adjust you query to limit by file type(s) & only allow xslt,pdf,doc,docx,etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most simple way would be to filter documents by file type.

[DocIcon field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.docicon%28v=office.12%29.aspx) specifies the document icon that is associated with the creation of the specified template document object. Bu default this field is not available in CQWP.

### How to configure CQWP to filter documents by file type

1)Export CQWP

2)Locate `CommonViewFields` element and set value `DocIcon,Lookup`

Example: `<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">DocIcon,Lookup</property>`

3) To make it available for filtering, locate `AdditionalFilterFields` element and set it value to `DocIcon`.

Example: `<property name="AdditionalFilterFields" type="string" >DocIcon</property>`

4) Save changes and upload web part, add web part on the page.

### Usage

Specify file types to display using `Additional Filters` property

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with the Additional Filters I can only add them 3. How can I add more than 3 filters?

Comment: Please follow the article: Adding more than three filters in CQWP (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/08/09/adding-more-than-3-filters-in-cqwp.aspx) to add more than three filters in CQWP

Comment: Funny enough I have just found that exact article. Cheers.